# Is this the right way to use python maigret module?

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I am using `maigret` module in the Django application to search usernames in social media. Maigret can only be used through CLI so I had to use subprocess to run and get the output. But is this the best way to do it? I couldn't find any other solution. Below is the function that I have created.

```
def SearchNames(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        name = data.get('name', '')
        network = data.get('network', '')
        output = subprocess.run('maigret {} --site {}'.format(name, network), shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout
        outputs = output.decode("utf-8").split("\n")
        matching = [s for s in outputs if "Search by username" in s][0]
        total_account_found = [int(s) for s in matching.split() if s.isdigit()][0]
        print({"accountsFound":total_account_found, "network":network})
        return JsonResponse({"accountsFound":total_account_found, "network":network}, safe=False)
    except:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Error occurred while searching for username'}, status=400)
return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request'}, status=400)
```

I wanted to know if there is a better way to use `maigret` other than subprocess.

Comment: Well, `maigret` is a Python module.  You can `import maigret` and call it from Python, but there aren't any good examples in the repository.  There are some tests that might guide you.